# How to map two matrix by each element and perform simple mathematical operation by each row?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two matrix `A` and `B` of equal dimensions see below. In `A` matrix I have the variables `a,b,c,d` which have direct correspondence with matrix `B` element by each row. In other words, for first row `{a, b, c, d}` we have `{2, 9, 6, 7}`, further for each element in both row `a=2, b=9, c=6 and d=7` similarly for other rows in both matrix.

```
A={{a, b, c, d}, {d, c, b, a}, {a, c, b, d}};
B={{2, 9, 6, 7}, {11, 3, 5, 12}, {12, 4, 1, 4}};
```

After mapping these two matrix, I want to perform simple mathematical operations (addition and subtraction). For example, for first row:

```
x1=a-d=2-7=-5
y1=b-a=9-2=7
```

similarly fir second row,

```
x2=a-d=12-11=1
y2=b-a=5-12=-7
```

I can map these two matrix by `Map[A,B]`, but I don´t know how to map each element of both matrix. Is there a way we can map each element and then by using loop we evaluate   `a-d, b-a` for each row?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look at what `{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}}.{{1, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}}` does, and see if you can adapt this to your problem.

Comment: Hi @J.M., in this way I couldn't reach to the solution, because In each row the order of variables `(a,b,c,d)` are changing. Further, list manipulation  `Function[A] /@ B` gives wrong values.  Actually, if we create somehow element by element correspondence then your solution might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't immediately give the full answer, in the hope someone would follow up on the hint in my comment. Anyway, the missing piece is to use `Ordering[]` to rearrange list `B`, like so:

```
MapThread[#1[[Ordering[#2]]] &, {B, A}].{{1, -1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}}
   {{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}}
```

A second method is to convert the data to an association, which can then be used for lookups:

```
{#[a] - #[d], #[b] - #[a]} & /@ MapThread[AssociationThread, {A, B}]
   {{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}}
```

Comment: Hi J.M, Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi J.M, I am trying to import all the variables in `A` by:
`A = Import[ "directory", "Table"]`, while I import these variable I couldn't apply your solution.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
MapThread[Block[{a, b, c, d}, # = #2; {a - d, b - a}] &, {A, B}]
(* {{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`):

```
{a - d, b - a} /. MapThread[Rule, {A, B}, 2]

(* {{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I use loop as a last resort in Mathematica and I believe there are other ways to solve this problem. However, I am using loop for this problem as it is quite intuitive. Please, let me know if you have trouble understanding the soln:

```
    A = {{a, b, c, d}, {d, c, b, a}, {a, c, b, d}};
    B = {{2, 9, 6, 7}, {11, 3, 5, 12}, {12, 4, 1, 4}};

    NN = Length[A];
    data = {};
     For[i = 1, i <= NN,
         a =.; b =.; c =.; d =.;
         Evaluate[A[[i]]] = B[[i]];
         values = AppendTo[data, {a - d, b - a}];
          i++];
    values
    (*{{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you @maeniss, I understand your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {{a, b, c, d}, {d, c, b, a}, {a, c, b, d}};

B = {{2, 9, 6, 7}, {11, 3, 5, 12}, {12, 4, 1, 4}};
```

**1.**

Create a list of associations

```
asc = MapThread[AssociationThread, {A, B}];
```

Use `Query`

```
Query[All, {#[a] - #[d], #[b] - #[a]} &] @ asc
```

{{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}}

**2.**

If the elements of `A` were strings,

```
asc = MapThread[AssociationThread, {Map[ToString, A, {2}], B}]
```

the `Query` would simplify to

```
Query[All, {#a - #d, #b - #a} &] @ asc
```

{{-5, 7}, {1, -7}, {8, -11}}